# Visual Studio C# form missing components

Tags: visual-studio-2008, forms

My lab partner and I are working on a school project in Visual Studio 2008 in C#.  He emailed me the latest version of the project.  When I open it, some, but not all, forms that I previously created are now missing all the components that were added to them.  However, when I run the project, the components are there and work.  Everything on the form except for the border is "hidden."

Any ideas how I can access the missing components and edit the forms?  ShowAllForms is active.

It appears something similar to the code below has been added to the .cs code for each form (but not by me).  I read elsewhere on the internet that this code could be auto generated by Visual Studios.  Could this be the problem?  If so, why is Visual Studios adding it to my code?

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // VideoPoker
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(804, 549);
            this.Name = "VideoPoker";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.VideoPoker_Load_1);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the InitializeComponent() method is automatically added by Visual Studio.

As th name implies, every property of the form itself is initialized and the same goes for any object that you put into the form within the Designer.
Everthing that you edit within the designer finally goes into this code section - automatically.

You should never edit this code manually.

Regarding the missing controls, I suppose that for some reason the code was deleted that puts them into the form's ControlCollection which is accessd via the property Form.Controls.

You should check, if the code in the InitializeComponent() method still contains lines like

```
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
```

for each control which is supposed to be on the form.

Those lines should be far down, near the method's end.

Comment: I wouldn't say NEVER modify the code manual, just make sure you know what you're doing if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio usually adds the method InitializeComponent under .Designer.cs and when you add new controls this method gets modified to add the new controls.  Here are the things you could try after taking backup of your existing files

1. Check whether InitializeComponent  contains code for all the controls in your form.
2. Clean the existing code and recompile the project.
3. In the solution explorer, ensure your designer.cs appears directly under your .cs and not under any other files (such as .resx etc). For example, if your designer file gets added under the .resx file accidentally you could try removing the designer file from your project (after taking backup) and then add it again. It should get added under .cs